# How to start and end date in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just to get this kind of URL `mysite/blog/post/01-09-2009/10-09-2009`
do I need to go for custom routing?

How my routing code would look like? below route will work?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyNewRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{stardate}/{enddate}",
    new { controller = "BlogController", action = "Post" }
);
```

How my action method signature would look like to deserialize start and end dates to action?

Comment: It would be better to use ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) for your dates. Whether your routes works or not depends on the other route definitions and where this one is placed in the order, and what the signature of your `post()` method is

Comment: It would certainly work if you made it `"blog/post/{startdate}/{enddate}",` and placed it as the first route definition, and your method is `public ActionResult Post(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)`